# How to split column in R if tidyr won't download?

Tags: r

I'm trying to split the date column in my df, which is in "year/month/day" format, in to three columns "month", "day", and "year". I've always done it before using tidyr::separate() with the following line  `data2<-separate(data2, Date,c("Year","Month","Day"))`. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make tidyr work on my machine anymore, and I now get the error response:

> "Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required"

In the absence of finding a solution to my issues with `tidyr`, what would be an alternative approach to accomplish the same task?

Comment: You could also reinstall the rlang and tidyr.  What is your R version

Comment: showing my ignorance on R details, how would I check that?

Comment: You can either do `sessionInfo()` and it gives the R version or use `R.Version()[c("major", "minor")`]

Comment: R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Comment: It is a bit old.  Now the version is `R 4.0.3` and this can affect the packages with tidyr, dplyr as they have some major changes and it requires at least R version >= 4.0

Comment: so the course of action then would be to uninstall R entirely, and reinstall?

Comment: In Windows, you can install a new version without uninstalling the old one.  It will create new repo etc as it is a major release  i.e. 4 instead of 3 and then start using the R 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply use `base R`

```
data2[c("Year", "Month", "Day")] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(data2$Date, "/"))
```

---

Or instead of splitting, can use `format` if we change the 'Date' to `Date` class

```
data2$Date <- as.Date(data2$Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
data2 <- transform(data2, Year = format(Date, "%Y"),
                    Month = format(Date, "%m"),
                    Day = format(Date, "%d"))
```

---

Or with `read.table`

```
data2[c("Year", "Month", "Day")] <- read.table(text = data2$Date, sep="/")
```

#### data

```
data2 <- data.frame(Date =  c("1999/05/26", "2012/10/12"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option with `tstrsplit`

```
setDT(df)[,setNames(tstrsplit(Date,"/"),c("Year","Month","Day"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or via `sapply`ing `strsplit` and defining the columns via indices:

```
s <- strsplit(df$date, "/")
df$year <- sapply(s, function(x) x[1])
df$month <- sapply(s, function(x) x[2])
df$day <- sapply(s, function(x) x[3])
```

Result:

```
df
        date year month day
1 2000/09/24 2000    09  24
2 2107/12/07 2107    12  07
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
      date = c("2000/09/24", "2107/12/07")
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lubridate package and combine it with dplyr

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
    df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(year = lubridate::year(date), 
                    month = lubridate::month(date), 
                    day = lubridate::day(date)
    )
```